# How to build a 15,000 Gauss hand-held electromagnet

Tags: solenoid, electromagnetic, magnet

I'm wondering if it's possible to build a small hand-held electromagnet shaped like a solenoid that is possible of producing a field of 15,000 Gauss.

I'm familiar with the formula for the strength of a field produced by a solenoid: field strength = (permeability * number of turns * amperage) / length.

By my calculations, if I can get a core with a u of 10^(-3), amperage of 5 from a Gates 5 amp-hour battery, and a length of 5cm, I would only need 15 turns.

Am I on the right track?

Comment: Note that if your battery is 6 volts the coil will dissipate 30 watts, and that sort of coil will kill itself in a very short time.

Comment: Too much power? Will the coil catch fire?

Comment: What about a 2 volt, 5 amp-hour Gates sealed lead acid battery? That's 10 watts. Still too much?

Comment: Maybe. It might just destroy the insulation and draw more current as the adjacent windings short out. But it's unlikely to end well.

Comment: How would you suggest building the electromagnet that I have in mind?

Comment: Any help?.........

Comment: Guess not......

Comment: Use uninsulated wire and a mostly open (skeletal) coil form that will tolerate high temperatures.  If you need to operate continuously, add a fan.

Comment: Thanks, but uninsulated wire? Won't the charge just run everywhere across the whole surface? I need it to stay in a single coiled path.

Comment: Thoughts?......

Comment: Isn't this 1.5 Tesla?

Comment: Yes. But 1 Gauss = 10^(-4) Tesla. So, 15,000 Gauss = 1.5 Tesla. Right?

Comment: Any advice for how to proceed?

Comment: Is it possible to build such a magnet?

Comment: Where do you want this field? That's the first question and allows you to design the gap and the pole pieces, the rest of the magnetic circuit will come from that. In the bulk of the core you'll need to keep the flux below about 1.2T with carefully shaped poles to concentrate it - unless you're using a better material than iron...

Comment: Where? At the end of the solenoid. Gap? Pole pieces? What are those things? I want to keep the flux low in the core? I thought one wanted it high. I might be getting some Metglas amorphous cobalt alloy.